# How to add drop pin in Google Map iOS

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I add "drop pin" and the dropping on above animation in Google Map iOS?
I can only find marker in SDK, and the `appearAnimation` property only provides pop up animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKPinAnnotationView) from MapKit. From the documentation on [Using the Standard Annotation Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW6):

```
MKAnnotationView* aView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                              reuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [GMSMarker Class reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker) it says for the appearAnimation property:

> Controls the animation used when this marker is placed on a GMSMapView (default   kGMSMarkerAnimationNone, no animation).

Using the [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) a marker can be made like this:

```
GMSMarker *startMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:@"NYC"];
startMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
startMarker.title = @"Start";
startMarker.snippet = @"My address";
startMarker.map = mapView;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set the title or snippet property of a Marker then the tooltip will show when tapped.

```
marker.title = @"Hello World";
```

and/or

```
marker.snippet = @"Hello Snippet";
```

Answer (score -1):

For swift:

```
locationMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
locationMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "testImage") as UIImage?
```